# Sending HTML content in API vulnerability risk

Tags: reactjs, api, security

I have a react application that builds an Editor component dynamically.
One of the fields in this editor is a **content editable div** that gets from API -json response- a content to be displayed in that div with some of the text highlighted or styled with any other html tags inside.

The user can change this content and I keep sending it back to API and getting it back from API to be displayed accordingly.

But I'm concerned about security, is this a risky vulnerability? How should I act in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to concern about security. I recommend to use [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html).

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused if to go with this approach (sanitize-html) or disable the dangerouslySetInnerHTML of div and decide on a protocol between the server and client to add html tags in client side according to some rules agreed between two sides. Not sure that that this will work at all (if I disable the dangerouslySetInnerHTML the html tags will be ignored I guess)! And the problem of man on the middle still exists anyway in this approach...

Comment: Get data (with HTML tags) from the server, make manipulation with data (with HTML tags). But don't post unsafe HTML to the server. Before post calls `sanitize-html` methods. `Sanitize-HTML` will remove or/and replace unsafe tags from posted data.